# URL rewrite and 404 error pages [SOLVED]

Tags: catalog, category, magento-1.8, url-rewrite

After installing Magento 1.8 CE and importing categories I realized that all category pages gives me an error. I have tried:

1. Truncate the core_rewrite_url table and regenerate
2. Re-index category url rewrite
3. Disable url rewrite in system-config-web

But nothing solves this issue. I don't know what I have to do, any idea welcome.

Comment: any custom extensions installed? anything in the error logs?

Comment: thank you david. I used store manager for category import. great product but I believe I made an error in details. i created a new database and import data with mageworks and now it works perfect. i believe it was a category path problem, i mean category path -> 1,3,10,334 etc brgds!

Comment: Please write the solution you found as an answer and accept it. Don't leave loose ends.

Comment: @Marius done...

Answer (score 1):

my solution was to use mageworks (free at http://www.magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension) and now it works perfect. i believe it was a category path problem, i mean category path -> 1,3,10,334. another great solution, in my opinion more complicated but great is to use MAGMI for import-export data into MAGENTO system. ( http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page )
brgds!